# LSI MSM on Windows : SSL error when connecting remotely to a Ubuntu server

Tags: lsi, megaraid

I've got LSI MSM (14.08.01.01) installed on a Windows Server. The manager works well here, and I am able to manage the local RAID on that server. However, when I attempt to connect to a Ubuntu server to manage its RAID i get the following error on the Ubuntu Server (which also runs MSM):

```
********************************* 
Number of Controller registered for AEN= 1
before creating SSL Soket in Framework isStandAlone() :false
INSIDE LINUX-X64 
 DCMD0->OPCODE IS 17301761INSIDE LINUX-X64 
 DCMD0->OPCODE IS 17301761The dcmd opcode is 17301761
AdapterSetTime.fireGetTimerDCMD() ctrl timestamp = 2015-4-30 23:40:39
AdapterSetTime.getSystemTimeStamp()System Time = 2015-4-30 23:40:40
AdapterSetTime.setTime() difference Time = 1
iniFlag isDISABLE
sslSession is INVALID.
```

It seems that the Ubuntu server is not too happy with the SSL session. I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, but I don't really know how to get any further on this one now. What can cause these errors on the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

1. Remove current installation of MSM manager (client side)
2. Start install MSM manager client side
3. Choose 'Custom installation' during setup
4. Set Key size to 1024
5. ???
6. Profit

The more elegant solution would be to change the key size to 2048 on the server side:

Upon installation user can still switch the keys and below were the steps to perform the same:

1. Stop MSMFramework Service.
2. Make sure service is Stopped
3. Edit the vivaldikey.properties available in below locations

   ```
     <MSM_HOME>\MegaRAID Storage Manager
     <MSM_HOME>\Framework
     <MSM_HOME>\MegaPopup
   ```
4. Comment/Uncomment the VIVALDI_KEY_FILE field for Key size selection
5. Save the vivaldikey.properties file.
6. Start the MegaRAID Storage Manager Framework service..
7. Start the MegaPopup (\MegaPopup\popup.sh)

See also: ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/CDR-X10_1.10_for_Intel_X10_platform/LSI/MSM/Linux/15.05.01.00/32bits/readme.txt